# How to read the specific part of file into the private data members

Tags: c++, class, file-handling

I am trying to read a text file in `virtual void BillRecord::ReadCustDetails(ifstream &fin)`that contains customer details. Codes works fine but I dont know how to read even the whole address and negative values and store them to private members. I have tried the following code but the output is wrong.

text file:

```
Phone
Origin
George Carter
24 Dingo St Exeter SA
-0.018
28

Gas
EA
Paul Scott
21 Beach Rd Barham NSW
15.48786
356567

Elect
...
```

my output:

```
Origin                         
George
Carter
0
24
```

Required output:

```
Origin
George Carter
24 Dingo St Exeter SA
-0.018
28
```

My program:

```
  public:
    BillRecord();
    virtual void ReadCustDetails(ifstream &fin);
  private:
    BillType BType;
    string Supplier; // Supplier's name
    string Name, Address; // Customer's name and address
    double BillAmount;// Amount in dollars and cents of this bill            
    int DaysSinceLastReading; // Days since last reading

};

 virtual void BillRecord::ReadCustDetails(ifstream &fin)
 {
        fin >> Supplier;
        getline(fin,Name);
        getline(fin,Address);
        fin >>AccountBalance;
        fin >>BillAmount;
        fin >>DaysSinceLastReading;
        fin >>i;
        DaysSinceLastReading=i;

    //put the code here for reading the customer details part of the file 
record only into the private data members

cout << Supplier<< endl;
cout << Name  << endl;
cout << Address << endl;
cout << BillAmount << endl;
cout << AccountBalance << endl;
}
```

Comment: what is wrong with your output? how should it look like?

Comment: `cin` reads till whitespace or endline, if you want to read more you need to use `getline`

Comment: or if it is always `firstname lastname` you can use two `cin`

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/read-file-line-by-line

Comment: btw there is no inheritance in the code you show here and the fact that the members are private is also rather irrelevant as long as you access them from within a member function

Comment: ..also you dont need that temporaries `s`,`d` and `i` you can simply write `std::cin >> Supplier;` instead of `std::cin >> s; Supplier = s;`. And last but not least I would suggest you to not use capital starting letters for variable names, they are usually reserved for class names

Comment: My output should be like the text file

Comment: I added getline in the program but the output is still same. I added the required output to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has just minor issues. try to be more specific. what is the real problem other than this code? you must have some issue in other functions. Try to post them in here. I have tried to fix up as much as I could.

```
void BillRecord::ReadCustDetails(ifstream &fin)
{

fin >> Supplier;
fin.ignore();
getline(fin,Name);
getline(fin,Address);
fin >> BillAmount;
fin >> AccountBalance;
fin >> DaysSinceLastReading;
cout << DaysSinceLastReading;

cout << Supplier << setw(16);
cout << Name     << setw(27);
cout << Address  << setw(15);
cout << BillAmount << setw(14);
cout << AccountBalance     << setw(8);
cout << DaysSinceLastReading  << setw(6);
}
```

Comment: Yes, i had issue with another function which i have just noticed.

Comment: try not to declare I in `ReadCustDetails` and just do it whatever I did. Try to learn the basics.